# In Microsoft Teams how to save Print Screen -> Ctrl+V images to our custom blob storage

Tags: node.js, azure, blob, microsoft-teams

I want to take Print Screen (prtscrn) and paste (Ctrl+V) it in Microsoft teams, this functionality is working but i want to save the pasted image into my custom storage.

i referred this blog: [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=typescript

But i am getting an error as **No renderer for this attachment**

My question is if i take screenshot and paste it in Microsoft teams is it possible to get that pasted image and save that image to custom storage.

Comment: Are you getting error while downloading the image in Bot code? Could you please share the screenshot of what you are trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you paste an image in MS teams chat, it does not take it as an usual attachment. Rather it receives as an image type and stores it in MS Team storage and sends the Image URL in Activity.Attachment[0].

1. you have to get the image from that URL and upload to your blob storage.
2. MS Teams attachment URLs are secured by a JwtToken, so we need to pass the token from our bot.
3. Here is a sample c# code for getting the image form MS Teams URL and
   save it to solution file. You can add this logic in ActivityHandler
   method.

   ```
   if (turnContext.Activity.Attachments != null && turnContext.Activity.Attachments.Count > 1
               && turnContext.Activity.Attachments[0].ContentType=="image/*")
           {
               var attachment = turnContext.Activity.Attachments[0];
               using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
               {
                   // MS Teams attachment URLs are secured by a JwtToken, so we need to pass the token from our bot.
                   var token = await new MicrosoftAppCredentials("appId", "password").GetTokenAsync();
                   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                   var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(attachment.ContentUrl);
                   var contentLenghtBytes = responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
                   // You could not use this response message to fetch the image for further processing.
                   if (responseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                   {
                       Stream attachmentStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                       attachmentStream.Position = 0;
                       var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(attachmentStream);
                       image.Save(@"ImageFromUser.png");
                       await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Attachment of {attachment.ContentType} type and size of {contentLenghtBytes} bytes received.");
                   }
               }
           }
   ```